# Heading of paragraph on left side

Tags: tables, sectioning, formatting, longtable

I want to list something in my document. Each point in the list has a short heading (one word, for example "Usecase"). This word should be on an own column to the left of the text which gets added under this point. The text is rather long.

Doing this with a table doesn't work, as tables do not support this if the whole stuff goes multipage. I know longtable, but longtable puts the whole text (the right side) into one row. If I do `\begin{longtable}{l|p{\textwidth}}` or something like that, it kind of sucks, too.

(as you can see in the code snippet above, I want to seperate the "heading"/name of the section with a vertical line from the text)

Adjusting manually the size of the text on the right doesn't seem to be a nice solution. Anyways, if this works, the text for one item isn't able to be a multipage text either.

So, I hope I made clear what my problem is. The point is, I don't even know what to google.

Comment: Sorry, but where is you "code snippet above"? Perhaps it would be better to supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather...

Comment: Well, I would do, but I have non, as I don't know how to achieve what I want... so I cannot get you a WME...

Comment: @musicmatze: Just because you don't know _exactly_ how to do it does not mean that you can't mock up a MWE that clearly shows what you want to specify and how you want the output to look. Basically, set up a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that illustrates the problem.  Its not that people here don't want to help, it's just not clear what it is that you desire, at least not to me. A MWE will make it clear how you want to specify things and what output you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're interested in a [`parcolumns`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parcolumns) setting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,parcolumns}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{\colchunk[1]{\hspace*{-\parindent}\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\desc}[1]{\colchunk[2]{#1}\colplacechunks}
\begin{document}
\begin{parcolumns}[
    colwidths = {1=3cm},% 2=\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm-2em\relax
    rulebetween = true,
    sloppy = true]{2}
  \heading{Usecase}
  \desc{\lipsum[1-2]}
  \heading{Another type of heading}
  \desc{\lipsum[1-2]}
\end{parcolumns}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

[image: Output]
Here's another solution based on `mdframed`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\newlength{\defparindent}
\setlength{\defparindent}{\parindent}

% The leftrule environment
\newmdenv[
linecolor=black,%
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
rightline=false,
rightmargin=0pt,
skipabove=0pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
backgroundcolor=white]{leftrule}

% Fix top alignment
\makeatletter
\renewrobustcmd*\mdf@makebox@out[2][\linewidth]{%
 \noindent\hb@xt@\z@{%
    \noindent\makebox[\dimexpr #1\relax][l]{\vtop{\vskip-\ht\strutbox\vskip-\dp\strutbox\relax#2}}%
 \hss}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=2cm,font=\normalfont]
\item[Usecase:]
\begin{leftrule}
    \lipsum[9-11]
\end{leftrule}
\item[Whatever:] 
\begin{leftrule}
    \lipsum[3-8]
\end{leftrule}
\item[Works:]
\begin{leftrule}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{leftrule}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```